# Show Task Manager details in Windows 8.1

Tags: powershell

This script restarts Taskmanager and show more details in its window and works on Windows 10

```
If (!(Test-Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager))
{
    New-Item -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager -Force
}
$preferences = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager -Name Preferences -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If (!($preferences))
{
    $taskmgr = Get-Process Taskmgr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If ($taskmgr)
    {
        $taskmgr | Stop-Process -Force
    }
    Start-Process -FilePath Taskmgr
}
$preferences = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager -Name Preferences -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$preferences.Preferences[28] = 0
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager -Name Preferences -Type Binary -Value $preferences.Preferences -Force
If ($taskmgr)
{
   $taskmgr | Stop-Process -Force
}
Start-Process -FilePath Taskmgr
```

but stucks on Windows 8.1 with an error

```
Unable to index in array NULL
+ $preferences.Preferences[28] = 0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: that means the array Preferences is null, i would suggest doing $preferences | select * and see what options you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$taskmgr = Get-Process Taskmgr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($taskmgr)
{
   $taskmgr.CloseMainWindow()
}
Start-Process -FilePath Taskmgr
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$taskmgr = Get-Process Taskmgr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($taskmgr)
{
   $taskmgr.CloseMainWindow()
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$preferences = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager -Name Preferences
$preferences.Preferences[28] = 0
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager -Name Preferences -Type Binary -Value $preferences.Preferences -Force
Start-Process -FilePath Taskmgr
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Try/Catch is better than -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue in most cases
2. You should validate the objects ie. before referring to items in arrays (like the length of an array)

If you remove the ErrorAction you might get an exception in this case which likely would show that the path does not exist. Or, $Preferences.Preferences does not have 28 items in the array.

/Patrik

Answer (score 0):

I can testify that killing *Task Manager* **forcedly** using `Stop-Process` does not create `Preferences` registry value (running `Windows 8.1/64`).

Creation `Preferences` registry value requires **regular completion** of  *Task Manager*, i.e. user's cooperation (see `$taskmgr | Wait-Process` in the following script).

```
$taskmgrPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager'
If (!(Test-Path $taskmgrPath))
{
    New-Item -Path $taskmgrPath -Force
}
$taskmgr = Get-Process Taskmgr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($taskmgr)
{
    #$taskmgr | Stop-Process -Force
    $taskmgr | Wait-Process
}
$preferences = Get-ItemProperty -Path $taskmgrPath -Name Preferences -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If (!($preferences))
{
    Start-Process -FilePath Taskmgr
    $taskmgr = Get-Process Taskmgr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If ($taskmgr)
    {
       #$taskmgr | Stop-Process -Force
       $taskmgr | Wait-Process
    }
    $preferences = Get-ItemProperty -Path $taskmgrPath -Name Preferences -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
$preferences.Preferences[28] = 0
New-ItemProperty -Path $taskmgrPath -Name Preferences -Type Binary -Value $preferences.Preferences -Force
If ($taskmgr)
{
   $taskmgr | Stop-Process -Force
}
Start-Process -FilePath Taskmgr          ## restart Task manager with modified properties
```

**Alternatively**, send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to the *Task Manager*. window i.e. `'%{F4}'` string in terms of both

- `.Sendkeys()` method of COM object `WScript.Shell`, or
- `::SendWait()` static method of .NET class `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]`

Comment: It works! But the task manager is running, it doesn't restart due to script stucks waiting for something. I have to close window, and only then script start it again with more details window.